# speed up function based on list comprehension

Tags: python, pandas, list-comprehension

I'm trying to get the 15 most relevant item for each users but every functions i tried took an eternity. (more than 6 hours i shutdown it after that ...)

I have 418 unique users, 3718 unique items.
U2tfifd dict has as well 418 entry and there is 32645 words in tfidf_feature_names.
Shape of my interactions_full_df is (40733, 3)

i tried :

```
  def index_tfidf_users(user_id) : 
    return [users for users in U2tfifd[user_id].flatten().tolist()]

def get_relevant_items(user_id):
    return sorted(zip(tfidf_feature_names, index_tfidf_users(user_id)), key=lambda x: -x[1])[:15]

def get_tfidf_token(user_id) : 
    return [words for words, values in get_relevant_items(user_id)]
```

then `interactions_full_df["tags"] =  interactions_full_df["user_id"].apply(lambda x : get_tfidf_token(x))`

or

```
def get_tfidf_token(user_id) : 
    tags =  []
    v = sorted(zip(tfidf_feature_names, U2tfifd[user_id].flatten().tolist()), key=lambda x: -x[1])[:15]
    for words, values in v :
        tags.append(words)
    return tags
```

or

```
def get_tfidf_token(user_id) : 
    v = sorted(zip(tfidf_feature_names, U2tfifd[user_id].flatten().tolist()), key=lambda x: -x[1])[:15]
       tags =  [words for words in v]
    return tags
```

U2tfifd is a dict with keys =  user_id, values =  an array

Comment: For performance questions, relevant information includes the size of each of the objects and what constitutes an "eternity". How many **users** do you have (even roughly), and how many **items** do you have per user (again, even roughly)?

Comment: I'll add it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things going on which *could* cause poor performance in your code. The impact of each of these will depend on things like your Python version (2.x or 3.x), your RAM speed, and whatnot. You'll need to experiment and benchmark the various potential improvements yourself.

#### 1. TFIDF Sparsity (~10x speedup depending on sparsity)

One glaring potential problem is that TFIDF naturally returns sparse data (e.g. a paragraph doesn't use anywhere near as many unique words as an entire book), and working with dense structures like numpy arrays is a strange choice when the data is probably zero almost everywhere.

If you'll be doing this same analysis in the future, it might be helpful to make/use a version of TFIDF with sparse array outputs so that when you extract your tokens you can skip over the zero values. This would likely have the secondary benefit of the entire sparse array for each user fitting in the cache and preventing costly RAM access in your sorts and other operations.

It might be worth sparsifying your data anyway. On my potato, a quick benchmark on data which should be similar to yours indicates that the process can be done in ~30s. The process replaces much of the work you're doing with a highly optimized routine coded in C and wrapped for use in Python. The only real cost is the second pass through the non-zero entries, but unless that pass is pretty efficient to begin with you should be better off working with sparse data.

#### 2. Duplicated Efforts and Memoization (~100x speedup)

If `U2tfifd` has 418 entries and `interactions_full_df` has 40733 rows then at least 40315 (or 99.0%) of your calls to `get_tfidf_token()` are wasted since you've already computed the answer. There are tons of memoization decorators out there, but you don't need anything very complicated for your use case.

```
def memoize(f):
    _cache = {}
    def _f(arg):
        if arg not in _cache:
            _cache[arg] = f(arg)
        return _cache[arg]
    return _f

@memoize
def get_tfidf_token(user_id):
    ...
```

Breaking this down, the function `memoize()` returns another function. The behavior of that function is to check a local cache for the expected return value before computing it and storing it if necessary.

The syntax `@memoize...` is short for something like the following.

```
def uncached_get_tfidf_token(user_id):
    ...
get_tfidf_token = memoize(uncached_get_tfidf_token)
```

The `@` symbol is used to signify that we want the modified, or **decorated**, version of `get_tfidf_token()` instead of the original. Depending on your application, it might be beneficial to chain decorators together.

#### 3. Vectorized Operations (varying speedup, benchmarking necessary)

Python doesn't really have a notion of *primitive* types like other languages, and even integers take `24` bytes in memory on my machine. Lists aren't usually be packed, so you can incur costly cache misses as you're plowing through them. No matter how little work the CPU is doing for sorting and whatnot, clobbering a whole new chunk of memory to turn your array into a list and only using that brand new, expensive memory once is going to incur a performance hit.

Many of the things you are trying to do have fast (SIMD vectorized, parallelized, memory-efficient, packed memory, and other fun optimizations) numpy equivalents AND avoid unnecessary array copies and type conversions. It seems you're already using numpy anyway, so you won't have any extra imports or dependencies.

As one example, `zip()` creates another list in memory in Python 2.x and still does unnecessary work in Python 3.x when you really only care about the **indices** of `tfidf_feature_names`. To compute those indices, you can use something like the following, which avoids an unnecessary list creation and uses an optimized routine with slightly better asymptotic complexity as an added bonus.

```
def get_tfidf_token(user_id):
    temp = U2tfifd[user_id].flatten()
    ind = np.argpartition(temp, len(temp)-15)[-15:]
    return tfidf_feature_names[ind]  # works if tfidf_feature_names is a numpy array
    return [tfidf_feature_names[i] for i in ind]  # always works
```

Depending on the shape of `U2tfifd[user_id]`, you could avoid the costly `.flatten()` computation by passing an `axis` argument to `np.argsort()` and flattening the 15 obtained indices instead.

#### 4. Bonus

The `sorted()` function supports a `reverse` argument so that you can avoid extra computations like throwing a negative on every value. Simply use

```
sorted(..., reverse=True)
```

Even better, since you really don't care about the sort itself but just the 15 largest values you can get away with

```
sorted(...)[-15:]
```

to index the largest 15 instead of reversing the sort and taking the smallest 15. That doesn't really matter if you're using a better function for the application like `np.argpartition()`, but it could be helpful in the future.

You can also avoid some function calls by replacing `.apply(lambda x : get_tfidf_token(x))` with `.apply(get_tfidf_token)` since `get_tfidf_token` is already a function which has the intended behavior. You don't really need the extra `lambda`.

As far as I can see though, most additional gains are fairly nitpicky and system-dependent. You can make most things faster with Cython or straight C with enough time for example, but you already have reasonably fast routines which do what you want out of the box. The extra engineering effort probably isn't worth any potential gains.

Comment: Thanks, a very high quality answer I learned a lot from your explanations and I will explore all the advice you gave me